# Packaging a simple perl script for use by "average Joes" running Windows

Tags: perl, cpan

I have a really trivial perl script that I would like to distribute to a number of clients who are not very computer savvy. They are all running Windows XP or above. Furthermore, it is safe to assume that they do not have Perl installed on their systems.

I'm looking for a Perl module or other solution that would allow me to do the following:

- The application should auto start upon login and minimize to the system tray until the user expands it by clicking on the system tray icon.
- When expanded from the system tray the application should provide a simple Windows GUI to the script. The GUI is super trivial: a status line showing the status of the application and a "Do stuff" button that will trigger the processing of the applications business logic.
- Windows-style ideally wizard based installation. I'd like to be able to able to distribute an `[application-name]-install.exe` that would guide the user through the installation. Perl plus dependencies should be installed behind the scene.

Are there any Perl GUI toolkits and/or installation tools that would help me achieve these things?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- [Win32::SysTray](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aSysTray)
- [Win32::GUI](http://p3rl.org/Win32%3a%3aGUI)
- [PAR::Packer](http://p3rl.org/PAR%3a%3aPacker) provided executable wrapped into [NSIS](http://nsis.sf.net)

There are many more ways to do it. I think these modules will get you started most easily.

Comment: +1 for pp, I've used it many times. Also after I was working on a gui project that was giving me problems with pp, I usually use the -x flag straight off, just fyi.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [perlapp](http://docs.activestate.com/pdk/8.0/PerlApp_overview.html) from ActiveState to compile scripts into self-contained exe. It is commercial, but did not have problems I sometimes ran into with PAR/pp.

When I need to package more than just .exe (database drivers, configuration, templates, etc), quick installer can be made with InnoSetup.